# JQUERY + Reload the Same DIV

Tags: php, jquery

I have an AJAX loaded DIV.

When on this page I can make some changes that involve table updates and after I make then I call the following code to refresh the DIV.

It does fadeout/in and ajax loader appears etc but the contents of the page remains the same.

Appears the .load() isn't getting a fresh copy of the php file from the server as it requires a refresh for the updated data to appear.

Any ideas how I can get the DIV to refresh? thx

```
function reloadDIV() {
  var ajaxgifloader = $('img#ajaxgifloader');
  var contentwrapper = $('div#contentwrapper');
        ajaxgifloader.show();
        contentwrapper.fadeOut('fast',
                function() {
                  contentwrapper.load('scripts/php/admin_sitearticles.php',
                  function() {
                     contentwrapper.fadeIn('slow');
                     ajaxgifloader.fadeOut();
                });
        });
}
```

Comment: after success target_div.html(response)

Comment: If this is a cache issue then changing the url to `'scripts/php/admin_sitearticles.php?time=' + +new Date()` would probably help.

Answer (score 0):

my appologies - I had the wrong path to the PHP file - thus no new contect... thankyou for tolerating me!!